# Object received does not correspond to model

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem, but I find it hard to express it. I receive from MQTT a message in byte[], I convert it into a String, then the result is sent to GSON which creates me a `JenkinsMqttObject`.

```
String messageToString = message.getPayload().toString();
JenkinsMqttObject monobjet = gson.fromJson(messageToString, JenkinsMqttObject.class);
```

In the example code, `JenkinsMqttObject` is very simplified. The problem I have is the following:

*MQTT* sends me an object which can be :

> "{"value1":20,"value2":40}

But that can also be :

> "{"value1":20,"value2":40,"value3":60}

So depending on the case, I receive an object that contains 2 or 3 attributes.
The problem is that I created a java model like this:

**JenkinsMqttObject.class**

```
private String value1;
private String value2;
private String value3;
//getter & setters...
```

The problem is that i say at GSON that the object received is of type JenkinsMqttObject but it's not all time right !

So i don't know at all, how to be able to receive an object in Java that can correspond or not to a model.

Thanks for help !

Comment: I think that when `value3` is missing in the json, gson will just set `value3` to `null`  in the `JenkinsMqttObject` instance. what problem exactly are you encountering?

Comment: .. I don't know how i found it was not working but it is, so put it as answer, it's the best.. Thanks..

Comment: @Kevin, I assumed that you don't have control on no of values you receive from payload. Accordingly I answered. But if you are sure you will get max 3 values, then your code will work. But you will get null if it is less than 3 as MarcoLucidi has pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already stated in the comments, when `value3` is missing in the json, `gson` will set `value3` to `null` in the `JenkinsMqttObject` instance. from [`gson` documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) (emphasis mine):

> - This implementation handles nulls correctly.
>
>   - While serializing, a null field is omitted from the output.
>   - **While deserializing, a missing entry in JSON results in setting the corresponding field in the object to its default value: null for object types, zero for numeric types, and false for booleans.**

Answer (score 1):

You should take help of **Map** or **HashMap** for your Model class. It should be similar to the class given below.

```
class JenkinsMqttObject{
    HashMap<String, String> values;
    //getters & setters
}
```

You have to modify the main code as below.

```
String messageToString = message.getPayload().toString();
HashMap<String,String> vmap = new Gson().fromJson(messageToString , new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
JenkinsMqttObject monobjet = new JenkinsMqttObject();
monobjet.setValues(vmap);
```

Now if you want to access any value, you can access it as below.

```
monobjet.getValues().get("value1");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was working with my actual modal without any changes.. it just put it as null. So ok for me

Answer (score 0):

As [RLD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63755999/6413377) suggests, `Map` is the way to go.

You can use `TypeToken` but you can also declare a specific class to avoid using beforementioned and make parsing even simpler so parse it straight into the map:

```
public class JenkinsMqttObject extends HashMap<String, Object> {}
```

Also I do not think that if you put `byte[].toString()` it will produce you valid JSON but costructing a new `String` objects from a `byte[]` will work:

```
JenkinsMqttObject monobjet = gson.fromJson(new String(message.getPayload()),
                                               JenkinsMqttObject.class);
```

Then it is just to:

```
monobjet.get("value1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the purpose, but ..new String(...)  produce : The constructor String(capture#2-of ?) is undefined
https://prnt.sc/uc74cn

Comment: Then `message.getPayload()` does not return `byte[]` but something else. And maybe you should then use `toString()`. What does it return?